# Просмотр файла .db в android studio

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, sqlite

Открыл файл базы данных в android studio как файл SQL, хотя были варианты открыть как текстовый файл. Открыв файл вот что я увидел(см. картинку), полагаю это произошло из-за того, что я использовал кирилические символы при создании бд.
Это нужнно как-то исправлять, например я хотя бы хочу открыть этот файл как обычный текстовый, но как я не знаю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это бинарный формат, его незачем открывать в текстовом редакторе.

Comment: Файл базы данных SQLite - бинарный. Его нельзя открыть "как текст".

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что бинарные файлы не редактируют в текстовых редакторах.

Comment: Да, наверное я был не прав. Как тогда мне поступить, что бы привести все это к нормальному виду?

Comment: @Felay открыть в специальном редакторе баз данных?

Comment: @pavel По другому никак, да?

Comment: @Felay, могу посоветовать DB Browser for SQLite, в нём можно составлять бд, редактировать и просматривать.

Comment: +1 за DB Browser for SQLite, хоть давно уже стараюсь не юзать SQLite, но ностальгический привкус от этой GUI как SQL browser запомню надолго. Быстрая и мощная штука, очень выручала для смежных query + Group_by все дела. эххх... Ну на вопрос то можно ответить. Почему сразу закрывать, я думаю это не первый человек кто из Device Explorer будет пытаться .db открыть. Хороший и полезный вопрос я считаю

Answer (score 3):

Нужно установить плагин на android studio (к примеру Database navigator), который может работать с файлами БД.

Как установить плагин: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617408/how-to-install-plugin-in-android-studio